Recent TV Show where mormon killed by pimp?
I remember a scene from a TV show somewhat recently where there were 2 missionaries, I believe Mormon, but possibly Jehovah's Witness, and they met a hooker (maybe 2?) and went back to their apartment, where 1 of them boys did whatever with the prostitute. When they couldn't pay, 1 of them got killed, and the other told the police/church that they were robbed. I can't remember the name of the show at all. Thanks in advance!
Edit - Additional details:
Released within the last year or 2, I believe. My brother was watching it and I believe it was a newer show. I only remember this episode, but I don't think they were prominent characters in the series. I don't think it was a cop show, necessarily, but I think this was just the plot of this particular episode.
Color TV Show, I believe it took place in current day.
There are 3 scenes I remember. The 1st was the 2 boys talking to the girls then going upstairs. One of the boys tried to talk the other out of it. The 2nd was in maybe an alleyway where the body was, with 1 of the boys talking to the police about the "robbery gone wrong" and the 3rd is the survivor talking to his pastor. I think he confessed to his pastor, but his pastor said not to tell the truth to protect the reputation of the other boy.
Hopefully these details help out a little.

Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
